# how to modify a text file that every line has same number of columns?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I've got a text file which includes several lines. Every line has words which are separated with a comma. The number of words in lines are not the same. I would like with the help of the `awk` command to make every line have same number of column. For example, if the text file is as follows:

```
 word1, text, help, test
 number, begin
 last, line, line
```

I would like the output be as the following which every line has same size in column with an extra null word:

```
 word1, text, help, test
 number, begin, null, null
 last, line, line, null
```

I tried the following code:

```
  awk '{print $0,Null}' file.txt
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw).

Comment: What's your field separator? Comma or Comma followed by one space?

Comment: Comma followed by one space.

Comment: Is it known in advance how many columns each row should have?

Comment: The answer is no and it is unknown.

Comment: If that's true, how do you know how many "nulls" to put at the end of the line?

Comment: `awk` is worlds' Swiss-Army Knife for text processing, see [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {OFS=FS=", "} 
       NR==FNR {max=max<NF?NF:max; next} 
               {for(i=NF+1;i<=max;i++) $i="null"}1' file{,}
```

first scan to find the max number of columns and fill the missing entries in the second round.  If the first line contains all the columns (header perhaps), you can change to

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=", "} 
       NR==1 {max=NF} 
             {for(i=NF+1;i<=max;i++) $i="null"}1' file
```

`file{,}` is expanded by bash to `file file`, a neat trick not to repeat the filename (and eliminates possible typos).

Comment: I haven't seen the `file{,}` trick before - can you explain how that works?

Answer (score 1):

Passing twice through the input file, using `getline` on first pass:

```
awk '
   BEGIN {
       OFS=FS=", "
       while(getline < ARGV[1]) {
           if (NF > max) {max = NF}
       }
       close(ARGV[1])
   }

   { for(i=NF+1; i<=max; i++) $i="null" } 1
' file.txt
```

Alternatively, keeping it simple by running `awk` twice...

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="file.txt"

maxfields=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=", "} {if (NF > max) {max = NF}} END{print max}' "$infile" )

awk -v max="$maxfields" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=", "} {for(i=NF+1;i<=max;i++) $i="null"} 1' "$infile"
```

Comment: IMHO writing a shell script to call awk twice and passing the result of one awk call to a second awk call as an external variable is not as simple as just running awk once to parse the file twice. It'll also be less efficient and obviously requires more code and duplicate code.

Comment: That usage of getline will spin off into an infinite loop if getline fails, it needs to be `while( (getline < ARGV[1]) > 0 )`. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 0):

Use these Perl one-liners. The first one goes through the file and finds the max number of fields to use. The second one goes through the file and prints the input fields, padded at the end by the `null` strings:

```
export num_fields=$( perl -F'/,\s+/' -lane 'print scalar @F;' in_file | sort -nr | head -n1 )

perl -F'/,\s+/' -lane 'print join ", ", map { defined $F[$_] ? $F[$_] : "null" } 0..( $ENV{num_fields} - 1 );' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/,\s+/'` : Split into `@F` on comma with whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)